# Renaming GeoPackage layer to be the same as GeoPackage file

Tags: qgis, python, batch, geopackage, rename

I have a GeoPackage file that has been renamed, but the layer inside the GeoPackage keeps the original name, is it possible to automatically put the same name on the layer as the file?

**Example:**
*Original GeoPackage file* : cidadedesaopaulo.gpkg 
*Layer name* : citiesaopaulo

*Renamed GeoPackage file* : Cidades-SP_Brasil.gpkg 
*Layer name* : citiesaopaulo 
*Desired layer name* : Cidades-SP_Brasil

There are hundreds of files to change, which will be a lot of work to do manually. How can I automate this process in QGIS?

I'm aware of how GeoPackage works, but this filename pattern (the layer with the same name as the GeoPackage file) is a requirement of my employer.
My question is if there is a way to change the layer name so that it has the same name as the GeoPackage. Whether using a programming language or the QGIS graphical modeler.

Comment: The geopackage itself is a container which can store multiple tables. It makes little sense to, as a default, change the content names when the object is copied. You can certainly rename contents as you wish (within format naming constraints). Please choose an intended environment, and include an attempt in that stack and an [Edit] to the Question.

Comment: I think its a shame that a client would impose such a weird constraint upon a naming convention. Im sure there is some legacy requirement behind this but still, whats the point..... rant over.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this. (You'll have to adjust it to match your exact
data/situation)

```py
import os 

geopackage_folder = r'/home/bera/Desktop'

for root, folder, files in os.walk(geopackage_folder):
    for file in files: #For all files in geopackage_folder, including all subdirectories
        if file.startswith('geopackage') and file.endswith('.gpkg'): #If the file is a geopackage named geopackage*.gpkg
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file) #Join path and filename together
            print(fullname)
            layer = QgsVectorLayer(fullname)
            for sublayer in layer.dataProvider().subLayers(): #Find the table(s) inside
                tablename = sublayer.split('!!::!!')[1]
                print(tablename)
                newname = file.split('.')[0]
                processing.run("native:spatialiteexecutesql", {'DATABASE':fullname,
                    'SQL':'ALTER TABLE {0} RENAME TO {1}'.format(tablename, newname)}) #Rename it
```

[image]

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57015320/how-to-list-all-layers-on-geopackage-using-pyqgis

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426495/how-do-you-rename-a-table-in-sqlite-3-0